# How to mute the microphone only for the own application in Android java?

Tags: java, android

i try to mute the microphone of the application.
I try it by using AudioManager.

```
    onCreate() {
       audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
       audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
       audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
    }
```

Is there another way to mute it only localy for my application because when i minimize the app and it goes in the background than its not possible to pick up calls or the send voicemessages because it mutes the mic for the whole device.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am having the same issue. I can try to unmute the microphone when app goes to background or terminated, but that is not guaranteed and will be a bad experience for the user.